# How to add a mouse listener to a JTree so that I can change the cursor (to a hand cursor) when hovering over a node?

Tags: java, mouse, jtree

As the question states, I'd like to set a mouse listener to my `JTree` so that I can change the cursor to a `HAND_CURSOR` when the user places their mouse over a node.

I already have a `MouseAdapter` registered on my JTree to handle click events, but I can't seem to get a `MouseMoved` or `MouseEntered`/`MouseExited` to work with what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `MouseMotionListener/Adapter`:

```
tree.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = (int) e.getPoint().getX();
        int y = (int) e.getPoint().getY();
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(x, y);
        if (path == null) {
            tree.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        } else {
            tree.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, this works great. I never thought to use a MouseMotionAdapter. Care to explain why this works and not a MouseAdapter using mouseMoved?

Comment: I'm sure this also works with a MouseAdapter -- the two only differ in the interfaces they adapt: MouseAdapter implements pretty much all mouse-related listeners (MouseListener, MouseWheelListener & MouseMotionListener) while MouseMotionAdapter only implements MouseMotionListener. The mouseMoved() method is declared in MouseMotionListener and is thus the same for both adapters. In the example we're only interested in the motion, so a MouseMotionListener/Adapter is sufficient, but feel free to use a MouseAdapter if your app also cares about other mouse events. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

In a JTree, each of tree node is showed by a label generated by the `TreeCellRenderer` associated to this tree. The usually used class is `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` which renders this (the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`). As a consequence, you can try adding this `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` a MouseMotionListener to toggle mouse cursor.

Notice adding MouseMotionListener to the tree will simply toggle mouse rendering when on Tree component, not when mouse is on a label.